# Conflict with dependency

Tags: android, android-studio

Just launched a new project and got an error(build failed).
Error message is :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'
>        Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in 
>       project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) 
>       differ

build.gradle:

[image: link for ScreenShot of build.gradle]

I am using android version 3.0.1.

Comment: Can you update your question with build.gradle?

Comment: Hey Sagar, i added screen shot of build.gradle.

Comment: please don't use image for your build.gradle code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to exclude your `com.android.support:support-annotations`

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```